# accessing vue js object in javascript

Tags: javascript, vue.js

In a Laravel blade template I can access some data using @{{list.length}}.

```
<template id="events-template">
      @{{list.length}}
</template>
```

How do I use this within a javascript function within the same view template?

Vue is defined in app.js as

```
var vm = new Vue({
    el: 'body',

});
```

app.js is called before the script in my view template

Comment: the list.length variable is a javascript variable or a php variable?

Comment: javascript - within my vue template, I can access it using the @{{variable}} syntax. The @ symbol is used to not confuse blade

Comment: that's what I though, but I didn't see it in your Vue definition that's why I asked

Answer (score 2):

First, be sure that you actually have defined the `list` var in your vue instance

```
data: {
    list: []
}
```

Then, to access the list var, use the instance scope, for example in some method

```
methods: {
    someMethod: function () {
        console.log(list) // undefined
        console.log(this.list) // []
    }
}
```